# Testing a disappearing alert box with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I am using Capybara and Selenium to test features. I have an alert message that will disappear after 2 seconds (i.e., the element is removed from html page).

Now, using Capybara to check if the element exists gives inconsistent results: sometimes it passes. Sometime it fails.

How should I fix this issue?

Comment: this should be a js spec

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It'll work

> page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept

Answer (score 0):

Is your alert, a browser alert box? Or an inbuild alert message box of your application?

If so, did you try the capybara method `has_no_css`?

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_no_css%3F-instance_method

I think capybara will wait until your alert box disappear.

Unless, you can use `has_css` to ensure you have your alert message, then use a sleep 2, and make sure with the `has_no_css` method that the box is no longer present.